# GStreamer live to RTMP server causes mysterious segfault

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, rtmp, raspberry-pi4

I'm attempting to set up a Raspberry Pi to stream the HQ camera module over RTMP to an Nginx server with Gstreamer 1.19.0 (built from source).

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 --no-fault -v \
    rpicamsrc ! queue \
  ! x264enc bitrate=1000 byte-stream=false ! video/x-h264 ! queue \
  ! h264parse ! video/x-h264 ! queue \
  ! flvmux streamable=true name=mux ! queue \
  ! rtmp2sink async-connect=true location=rtmp://my-cool-server.com/live/key sync=true
```

After about 5 seconds, the pipeline crashes with `Segmentation fault`. This does not occur when streaming to a `fakesink`, or to `hlssink`, but only when streaming to `rtmp2sink`. I've tried both a mux.com streaming endpoint, and an `nginx_rtmp_module` enabled server I have running on Linode, and the problem is identical. Both of those servers work just fine when streaming from OBS.